# How to resume react-native app from background

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I need to resume an application from background, the stack is:

1. My RN app run a promise that open another app
2. When the task on the other app is completed the promise is resolved by the other app (my RN app is in background)
3. In the promise callback I need to take back my RN app from background to foreground

I have tried using `Linking` feature calling my RN app scheme but nothing happens, the other app remains in foreground and my RN app in background.

Any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: The other app will need to invoke a url to open your app. Once your app is not the foreground app there is no action it can take to become the foreground app. The user needs to open it or the current foreground app needs to open it via url.

Comment: Hi @Paulw11 , so it isn't possible :( thank you